# Missing .ko file during installation of a wifi driver, what should I do?

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu

I would like to use Kubuntu instead of Windows, so I'm currently running Kubuntu with VM VirtualBox. I (virtually) plug my usb key with the driver of my Wi-fi key, and the Wi-fi key itself. Then I copy the driver on the Desktop, and I simply do a "sudo make install" in the makefile directory. Then the konsole is saying to me that there's a missing .ko file (m7662u.ko).
I'm a new user so I almost don't know anything about drivers and Linux, I would appreciate a simple help from you with good explaining !
Thanks :D

Here are the konsole's line :

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~/Desktop/DPO$ sudo make install
make -C /home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux -f Makefile.6 install
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux'
rm -rf /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA
mkdir /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA
cp /home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/conf/RT2870STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/.
install -d /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install -m 644 -c mt7662u_sta.ko /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/
install: cannot stat 'mt7662u_sta.ko': No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [Makefile.6:784: install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux'
make: *** [Makefile:483: install] Error 2
```

After a simple sudo make, I'm getting this :

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~/Desktop/DPO$ sudo make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools'
/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7662u
chipset = mt7632u
chipset = mt7612u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/symbol.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:391: LINUX] Error 2
```

Here's the forum for this issue : [Having issue with a simple make, what should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234900/having-issue-with-a-simple-make-what-should-i-do)

You can download the driver here :
https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/mt7612u

Answer (score 0):

You probably first have to run `make` in the directory of the module. When `make` finishes without errors, you can do a `sudo make install`.

Comment: Yeah, but what's the directory of the module ?