# Having issue with a simple make, what should I do?

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, make

I'm trying to install a driver for a wi-fi key. So I go into the directory and type "sudo make", but I'm getting this :

```
kubuntu@kubuntu:~/Desktop/DPO$ sudo make
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools'
/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/tools/bin2h
chipset = mt7662u
chipset = mt7632u
chipset = mt7612u
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/5.4.0-26-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/kubuntu/Desktop/DPO/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
  YACC    scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.[ch]
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/parser.tab.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/preprocess.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/symbol.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/kconfig/conf
scripts/kconfig/conf  --syncconfig Kconfig
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.c', needed by 'arch/x86/tools/relocs_32.o'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:232: archscripts] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:391: LINUX] Error 2
```

Here's the driver : https://www.mediatek.com/products/broadbandWifi/mt7612u

I'm a new Kubuntu user so I would be greatful to you if you try to explain everything xd

Comment: The `README_STA_usb` file says *"Supporting Kernel: linux kernel 2.4 and 2.6 series."* - are you sure it's expected to work on a Linux 5.x series kernel?

Comment: In that case, what should I do ? I almost don't know anything about Linux.

Comment: @PapyNeko https://github.com/apxii/mt7612u is probably a good bet.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with this driver :(

Comment: Did it not work [out of the box](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/mediatek)? You didn't need `sudo` for `make`, only for `make install`.